# Definition of density function for a random vector $(X,Y)$, where $X$ is absolutely continuous and $Y$ is discrete.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence, density-function

Consider a random vector $(X,Y)$. Denote by $F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ its distribution function and by $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ its density function (if it exists). The definition of $f_{(X,Y)}$ varies depending on $(X,Y)$:

1. Case $(X,Y)$ is a discrete random vector: then $f_{(X,Y)}$ is the function living in $[0,1]$ such that $$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\sum_{m:\,m\leq x}\sum_{n:\,n\leq y}f_{(X,Y)}(m,n).$$
2. Case $(X,Y)$ is an absolutely continuous random vector: then $f_{(X,Y)}$ is the function living in $[0,\infty)$ such that $$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y f_{(X,Y)}(u,v)\,dv\,du.$$

What happens when $X$ is absolutely continuous and $Y$ is discrete? For me, in this case, the density function $f$ should be the function satisfying
$$ F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\sum_{m:\,m\leq y}\int_{-\infty}^x f(t,m)\,dt.$$ Is this correct? If it is, is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$?

Comment: Remark: in the second case $f_{(X,Y)}$ can also take values in $(1,\infty)$. Unfortunately I must leave now.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you're absolutely right. I edited the question.

Comment: "Density" in "density function" usually refers to densities with respect to the Lebesgue measure hence, by construction, none of your examples can have a density. The function in your case 1. is not a density but a "mass function". The function in the mixed case at the end of your post is neither a density function nor a mass function, a formal notation for the probability distribution in this case being $$P_{(X,Y)}(dx,dy)=\sum_nf(x,n)\,\left(\mathrm{Leb}\otimes\delta_n\right)(dx,dy)$$

Comment: @Did My question came from an exercise I had to do in class. It said to find the joint distribution of $Z$ and $W$, where $Z=\min\{X,Y\}$, $W=1_{\{Z=X\}}$ and $X,Y\sim\text{exp}(\lambda)$ are independent. So, they are asking me to write $F_{(Z,W)}(z,w)$, right? (I was confounded because $Z$ is absolutely continuous and $W$ discrete). And to check independence, I need to check that $F_{(Z,W)}(z,w)=F_Z(z)F_W(w)$.

Comment: Not every probability measure (aka, probability distribution) has a probability density function (PDF). Every probability distribution corresponds to a cumulative distribution function (CDF). But the CDF is not always the best way to characterize a probability distribution, even when no PDF exists. In the case you have in mind, by far the best approach would be to reach a formula for $P_{(Z,W)}$ similar to the formula in my previous comment.

Comment: The independence of $(Z,W)$ corresponds to the case when the function $f$ in the RHS of the formula in my comment is $f(x,n)=g(x)h_n$ for some function $g$ and some sequence $(h_n)$.